# Need some help in understanding a root test with given answer

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

[image]

Trying to proof the convergent of the series in the box by root test, the answer is as shown.

However two parts which I do not understand

1. why does the equation became $(1+1/n)^n$ instead $(1+1/n)^2$
2. why is the lim of $(1+1/n)^n=e$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) $\sqrt[n]{ x^{n^2}} = (x^{n^2})^{1 \over n} = x^{n^2*{1 \over n}} = x^n$

2) $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+{1 \over n})^n = e$ is a well-known statement (and canonically is the very definition of $e$). The proof is usually provided somewhere around the beginning of the course. To just show $\exists \lim_{n 
\to \infty}a_n > 1$ where $a_n = (1 + {1 \over n})^n$ show that ${a_{n+1} \over a_n} \ge 1$ and $b_n = (1+{1\over n})^{n+1}$ is eventually decreasing.

Comment: I guess I mixed up $x^{n^2}$ with $(x^n)^2$